# Why my jenkins docker container stops by itself?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have started my `jeninsci/blueocean` container by

```
nohup docker run -u root \
--rm \
-d \
-p 8080:8080 \
-p 50000:50000 \
-v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
jenkinsci/blueocean &
```

I think everything is going well even I close my commad line terminal,but the container just don't keep alive after sometime when I check it.Could anyone please tell me how to keep the container running so that I can make good use of this jenkins image?

Answer (score 0):

Use `docker run -d` rather than nohup solved the problem.